# What's the probability of a gambler losing \$10 in this dice game? What about making \$5? Is there a third possibility?

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes, markov-chains

Can you please help me with this question:

> In a gambling game, each turn a player throws 2 fair dice. If the sum of numbers on the dice is 2 or 7, the player wins a dollar. If the sum is 3 or 8, the player loses a dollar. The player starts to play with 10 dollars and stops the game if he loses all his money or if he earns 5 dollars. What's the probability for the player to lose all the money and what's the probability to finish the game as a winner? If there some 3rd possibility to finish the game? If yes, what's its probability?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[*edit:* Apparently I misread the question. The player starts out with 10 dollars and not five.]

Given that "rolling a 2 or 7" and "rolling a 3 or 8" have the same probability (both occur with probability 7/36), the problem of the probability of a player earning a certain amount of money before losing a different amount of money is the same as the problem of the [Gambler's Ruin](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambler%27s_ruin).

What's different when considering individual rounds is that there's a possibility of a tie. But because a tie leaves everything unchanged, the Gambler's Ruin still applies simply because we can simply consider only events that *do* change the state of each player's money.

Therefore, the probability that the player makes \$5 before losing \$10 is the same probability as flipping coins against somebody with $5, or 2/3. And the probability of the opposite event is 1/3.

The third outcome, that the game goes on forever, has a probability that vanishes to zero.

Answer (score 2):

The game is fair as $P(2 \text{ or } 7)=P(3 \text{ or } 8)=\frac 7{36}$, so if we ignore the non-paying rolls, it just flipping a coin.  As the game is fair, $\frac 23$ of the time he will earn $5$ and  $\frac 13$ of the time lose $10$.

Comment: Thanks a lot, now it's clear....